# How to Remove page from stack in prism xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I have two pages when user open application first page get data ,
I created another page and when click add in first one it navigate to the second page , I want when adding the required data in the second page and click submit first page is removed and created again with the newest data

first page is `CustomerAddressesPage` and second one is `AddNewAddressPage`

this is my code

```
    await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("/CustomerAddressesPage/AddNewAddressPage/CustomerAddressesPage");
```

It got me error

```
Removing views using the relative '../' syntax while navigating is only supported within a NavigationPage
```

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you exactly how you can fix the issue.

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("/NavigationPage/CustomerAddressesPage/AddNewAddressPage/CustomerAddressesPage");
```

This of course assumes that you have registered the base NavigationPage from Xamarin.Forms for Navigation or have a custom NavigationPage that was registered with that key.

Comment: what's the navigationpage ? how can i register it ?

Comment: You can see more about what a NavigationPage is and does [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical). You can register it just like you would any other page for Navigation `containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>()`